# How to list files for the specific environment variable?

Tags: linux, macos, bash, list, variables

I am using Mac OS 10.9, currently I am having trouble to find out where does the specific environment coming from and knowing where it declares.

For example: I want to know where is the `PATH` being declared and set. Since it can be set anywhere in `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` or `.anyfile_and anywhere_that_set_it_and_declare_it`. Now, what is the easiest way using bash to list all files where the `PATH` variable being assigned?

**NOTE**: there are correct answers by Jahid and others using `grep`. I accept that answer since it works as expected **BUT**, I am waiting for someone answer with much better speed. Because it will take *forever* to run `grep -r` with `/` at the end.

Comment: Are you interested in the environment variables that are set in a shell session (e.g. in Terminal)? Or those that affect GUI apps launched from the Finder or Dock?

Comment: @KenThomases Yes, I am only interested the environment variables in a shell session from Terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
grep -r -e "export PATH " -e "export PATH=" .
```

using `"export PATH "` with grep will deal with assignments having indentation between `PATH` and `=`

Note: `.` means current directory. You can replace it with a full path of a directory or if you want to search in the whole filesystem, replace it with `/`

Comment: didn't give me anything, after 1 hour trying. I also removed the "." in the latest command. Like i said in the question, it could be anywhere and anyfiles.

Comment: @exodream, That `.` is necessary. If you want to omit it, then replace it with a directory  path where you want to do this search. and to search whole filysystem, replace it with `/`

Comment: I hope if i can get it done within 1-2 seconds. So, I am waiting for other answers with much better speed. In the meantime, i accept ur answer.

Answer (score 0):

Bash doesn't track provenance for variables, what I suggest is using grep to search for instances of the `PATH` variable, for example: `$ grep -r PATH .`